# Android Room LIKE Collection

Tags: sql-like, android-room

The Room library claims it can automatically expand collections, for example on [IN](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html#daos-query-collection-args), which is a fairly simple example involving a single operator expansion.  Does anyone know if they can automatically expand LIKE?

> @Query("SELECT * column LIKE :foobar FROM table")

```
foobar: {%foo%, %bar%}
```

Expansion:

> "SELECT * column LIKE %foo% AND column LIKE %bar% FROM table"

Obviously a far less trivial expansion, not to mention the ambiguity of the AND/OR.

Comment: Do you mean `SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE :foobar`? If so, I will be rather surprised if Room supports expanding that the way that you seek.

Comment: That was my thought as well.  It got me thinking and I ended up realizing that my DB design was part of the issue.  I should be able to eliminate some of the LIKEs with clever hierarchy design and/or junction tables.  This database in my ignorance early on is treated more like a spreadsheet.

Comment: Beyond that, `LIKE` is slow, particularly with a leading `%`, as indexes are useless. It requires a full table scan, examining each row individually to see if it matches. Use `LIKE` sparingly. And if it's really for user-supplied search strings, consider FTS3/FTS4/FTS5 (though Room doesn't support those either, alas).